# Test Cases states Failed but value returned is true

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have written up a simple sample code to understand GMOCK used for unit testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
using ::testing::AtLeast;
class A {
public:
    void ShowPub1()
    {
        std::cout << "A::PUBLIC::SHOW..1" << std::endl;
    }
    int ShowPub2(int x)
    {
        std::cout << "A::PUBLIC::SHOW..2" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

class MockA : public A{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(ShowPub1, void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(ShowPub2, int(int x));
};
```

Below is my test code - I just wish to call ShowPub2 method of class A. I was expecting the statement **A::PUBLIC::SHOW..2** to get printed at console - but it just did not happen and the test case also failed though the method is hardcoded to return true:

```
TEST(FirstA, TestCall) {
    MockA a; 
    EXPECT_CALL(a, ShowPub2(2)) 
        .Times(AtLeast(1));
    a.ShowPub2(2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(a.ShowPub2(2));
}
```

GMOCK test code execution output - I am not sure why the output **A::PUBLIC::SHOW..2** did not rendered in console and test case failed:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from FirstA
[ RUN      ] FirstA.TestCall
c:\users\user1\documents\c and c++\gmock\gmock1\gmock1\gmock1.cpp(78): error:
Value of: a.ShowPub2(2)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] FirstA.TestCall (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from FirstA (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] FirstA.TestCall

 1 FAILED TEST
Press any key to continue . . .



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mocked methods must be virtual: https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md .

Comment: I made my both methods as virtual but still the same issue - am I missing something? virtual void ShowPub1() {} and virtual int ShowPub2(int x) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clarification is needed here..

Creating a `Mock` class means that the Mock methods are generate with its own implementations. These line of code

```
MOCK_METHOD0(ShowPub1, void());
MOCK_METHOD1(ShowPub2, int(int x));
```

doesn't mean it will call parent implementation of `ShowPub1 / ShowOub2`. This only means that you'll get a function (Mock) with same signature as that of the class you're mocking.

The test fails because of this line

```
EXPECT_TRUE(a.ShowPub2(2));
```

Since the original implementation is not called, this function fails.

The test function should be written as

```
TEST(FirstA, TestCall) {
    MockA a;
    EXPECT_CALL(a, ShowPub2(2)) .Times(AtLeast(1));
    a.ShowPub2(2);
  }
```

Here you're testing the behavior that the function is called at least once and the test will be successful with that.

If you want to test the functionality of a function, write separate tests. Mocking will not solve the problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks - then when do we mock a function and what it is used for

Comment: Mocking is mainly used for testing interface behavior. for example you pass `Mock a` to a function expecting `class A` as parameter. Inside this you can do some functionality which makes use of functions defined in 'class A'  .  Mocking is only meant for verifying the same. use `EXPECT` to find out the functional behaviour

Comment: Can you please provide test case code to test my Class Methods implementation? I tried to do the same but compiler stated - "error C2039: 'gmock_ShowPub2': is not a member of 'A'" for line EXPECT_CALL(a, ShowPub2(2)).Times(AtLeast(1)); when I do not create MOCK class and directly write test cases

Comment: you don't need to mock for testing the functionality use code directly  `
TEST(FirstB, TestCall) {
 A a1;
 EXPECT_TRUE(a1.ShowPub2(2));
}
`

Comment: Got it and got the same output thanks a lot for the clarification - can you please provide a mock method example for better understanding

Comment: This link has an example https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md

Comment: Also, if you've liked my answer .. may be you can consider upvoting :)

Comment: Thanks for the link - you mean to say that painter.DrawCircle in the example at link will call turtle::PenDown method but the mock function of same will be invoked (not the actual implementation) - also is it possible to inject our code in the mock method

Comment: No its not possible to inject the code into mock function. if you see the example the `Painter` takes Mock inside the constructor. The behavior is validated once the constructor makes a call to mock object at least once